# How to generate an audio waveform from an HTML5 web video?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, webrtc, html5-audio

Given a plain web video, e.g.:

```
<video src="my-video.mp4"></video>
```

How could I generate its audio waveform?

Is it possible to generate the waveform without playing the video?

---

**Notes:**

- I'm interested in the available APIs to achieve this, not a "how to render a waveform to a canvas" guide.
- Plain JavaScript, please. No libraries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might try [AudioContext.decodeAudioData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BaseAudioContext/decodeAudioData), though I can't tell whether video medias are well supported or not, it will probably depends a lot on the codecs and the browsers.

I am a bit surprised to see that FF, chrome and Safari accept it with an mp4 with and mpeg4a audio inside.

If it works, then you can use an [OfflineAudioContext](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OfflineAudioContext) to analyze your audio data as fast as possible and generate your waveform data.

---

See also [MDN article on Visualizations with Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API/Visualizations_with_Web_Audio_API)

Comment: There is no difference between mp4 and m4a except the extension - it just makes it easier to discern what the content is about (and the browser cannot rely on the extension alone).

Comment: There is btw. no need for the offlinecontext as the decodeAudioData will hand the decoded sample buffers which can be used for waveform plotting.

Comment: @K3N no I mean a video file which audio stream is encoded as mpeg4a, not an audio file encapsulated in a mp4 container.

Comment: And the AudioBuffer only gives the raw PCM data, indeed enough for a waveform, but if OP needs to analyze this data, then the use of an OfflineContext makes sense.

Comment: Agree, and even if it's just to render the entire waveform of the video in one go (ala Soundcloud) then the offline context will give the proper tools. +1 (I originally took it as he wanted a scope visualizer for video files' audio, but I probably misunderstood).

Comment: @Kaiido @K3N Would you mind creating a minimal running example to demonstrate the idea with `OfflineAudioContext`?

Comment: @MishaMoroshko sorry didn't got too much time during this long week-end, and when I fast tried to make you something, I found out that it might not be as easy as I first thought... [Here is a minimal and fast written example](https://jsfiddle.net/Lhqqfsac/) of what I had in mind, but it unfortunately only works in Firefox... Chrome and Safari won't fire the processor's event. I would have to dig a little more to find a workaround for these browsers. Maybe processing the buffer as a batch and passing slices directly to the analyzer would do, but I still didn't get enough time to try.

Answer (score 0):

If you will use web audio API, you will render on the client side.
You will not control the quality of experience because rendering may cause memory and time issues for clients.
you can generate an image of the waveform using FFmpeg on the backend and pass it to the front.
It is pretty simple.

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Waveform

example: 
ffmpeg -i C:\test.mp3 -filter_complex "showwavespic=s=640x120" -frames:v 1 C:\waveform.png